# Regex not validating end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, end-of-line

Consider the following scenario (Javascript code):

```
regex = new RegExp((/([\d,.]+)[ $]/));
value = "2.879"
```

The regexp doesn't match value, but it matches (value+" ") therefore i think that the $ is not matched? Why is that?

Shouldn't the $ validate the end of string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Special characters like `$` don't have the same meaning inside a character class. In a character class they're just characters, so `[ $]` will match either the space character or the `$` character. It won't match the end of a string.

If you want to match either a space character or the end of the string, you should use alternation, i.e. `( |$)`.

Comment: Thanks.Great Answer ! Do you know if i can avoid capturing grouping though?

Comment: Use `?:` to start a non-capturing group (i.e. `(?:pattern)`)

Comment: James has got it: `(?: |$)`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for bothering you so much. (If you want please let me know if there is a system to select this as the answer to the question)